# Summation that appears to be zero

Tags: integration, limits, summation

Here is the expression in question:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Big[2 + \frac{3}{n}k\Big]^2 \Big(\frac{3}{n}\Big)$$

The first thing I noticed was this: $$\frac{3}{n}$$

I figured that as `n` approaches infinity, this value would approach zero, so the value for the entire expression would be 0.

The real answer is 39. Can someone please explain this? I know it must have to do with integration, but I don't see why.

Comment: $\frac{3}{n}$ certainly approaches $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, but the number to terms in the sum approaches infinity. This gives something of the form $0 * \infty$, which may be (and in this case is) some other number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the expression to the right of the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ is a Riemann sum for $\int_0^3 (2+x)^2\,dx$. An antiderivative is $\frac{1}{3}(2+x)^3$. So the integral is $\frac{1}{3}(5^3-2^3)$, which is $39$.

Since the limit of the Riemann sum as $n\to\infty$ is the definite integral. we can conclude that the limit is $39$.

**Remark:** Here is a messier approach. Expand $\left(2+\frac{3k}{n}\right)^2$. Now use the formulas for the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers, and for the sum of the first $n$ perfect squares, to find an explicit formula for our sum. Finally, take the limit as $n\to\infty$. The Riemann sum approach is more pleasant.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. Can you just clarify where you got $\int_0^3 (2+x)^2\,dx$ from? Sorry if this is obvious.

Comment: Not obvious until you have done a bunch of these. The $\frac{3}{n}$ suggests what to do. Divide the interval $[0,3]$ into $n$ equal parts. So each part has width $\Delta x=\frac{3}{n}$. Take the part from $\frac{3(k-1)}{n}$ to $\frac{3k}{n}$. The function value at the right end of that part is $\left(2+\frac{3k}{n}\right)^2$. Multiply by $\Delta x$ and you get a good approximation to the area under the curve, from $3(k-1)/n$ to $3k/n$. Now add up, $k=1$ to $n$. You get a good approximation to the area from $x=0$ to $x=3$. As $n$ gets large, the approximation gets better and better.

Answer (score 1):

This is how doing it the hard way looks.

\begin{align}
   \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}
   \left[2 + \frac 3nk \right]^2 \left(\frac 3n\right)
   &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac 3n \right) \sum_{k=1}^{n}
   \left(2 + \frac 3nk \right)^2 \\
   &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac 3n \right) \sum_{k=1}^{n}
   \left(4 + \frac {12}{n}k + \frac{9}{n^2}k^2 \right)\\
   &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac 3n \right)
   \left[4n + \frac{12}{n} \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 
   \frac{9}{n^2}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \right]\\
   &= \lim_{n\to\infty}
   \left[12 + \frac{18(n+1)}{n} + \frac{9(n+1)(2n+1)}{2n^2} \right]\\
   &= 12 +18+9\\
   &= 36
\end{align}